# What is this Unicoin business?

Tags: support

The question is in the title. What do the Unicoins do for us? Why are they on MSE? What is this mining business about?

Comment: @AlexBecker: I have a related question which can likely be solved in one line and is not worth another thread: I mined some extra points and then spend all my unicorns on the "no downvote" power to spam some edgy stuff - and then it got deleted. I see how the April fools joke runs against the use of the reputation system, but how would I bring that power to use, one of the expensive ones, if you're not allowed to post answers which would get negative reputation? I get the message that the MathSE community is serious bizness, but in that case can I get me unicorns back to buy something else?

Comment: You can pat yourself on the back if you realized it was an April Fool "joke" before you came here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's that day of the year that big sites decide that they have to prank their users with extremely non-funny jokes (in most cases, Google did have some brilliant jokes in the past, though).

Comment: Actually based on early reports of the rhinoceros

Comment: Are you saying I have a big nose? :-P

Comment: I enjoyed turning comments into cyan Comic Sans... it should be made a permanent feature on meta. At least for uptight discussions about the appropriateness of this or that.

Comment: Asaf, i have no way of knowing. i had a big nose, then got head-butted in a soccer game about 1988. After three operations, I have a modest nose and can breathe easily with my mouth closed

Comment: I am going to divide everyone's rep by $10$ mwahahahahah.

Comment: Not fair. It doesn't even show *me* any decrease in rep. This is seriously unfunny.

Comment: It's not that bad, I just spend $90$ unicoins to boost my reputation ten times ;-p

Comment: The recycle feature is broken. Buy the power ups again drop your reputation back to normal. What a fool I am. Today is my day!

Comment: @achille: My day is every other day.